# TypeError object is not a function when parsing object

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to parse the values below based on a search criteria and then print the result to a table. I am able to correctly parse the desired results to console or print all the results to a table. Below is my attempt to merge both functions. I end up with a type error `TypeError: obj.list[i].forEach is not a function`. From searching, I believe it is because it is an object and not an array though have been unable to parse the object correctly. How can I correct the issue in order to correctly parse the object?

```js
var obj = {
  "list": [{
      "name": "my Name",
      "id": 12,
      "type": "car owner"
    },
    {
      "name": "my Name",
      "id": 13,
      "type": "car owner2"
    },
    {
      "name": "my Name4",
      "id": 14,
      "type": "car owner3"
    },
    {
      "name": "my Name4",
      "id": 15,
      "type": "car owner5"
    }
  ]
};

var tableBody = "";

var columns = [];

// Create the header record.
tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";
for (var prop in obj.list[0]) {
  if (obj.list[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    // Append properties such as myid, fname, lname etc.
    tableBody = tableBody + ("<th>" + prop + "</th>");

    // Also keep a list of columns, that can be used later to get column values from the 'data' object.
    columns.push(prop);
  }
}
tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>";

var results = [];
var searchField = "name";
var searchVal = "my Name";
for (var i = 0; i < obj.list.length; i++) {
  // search term
  if (obj.list[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
    // Create the data rows. 
    // I get an error here: 
    obj.list[i].forEach(function(row) {
      // Create a new row in the table for every element in the data array.
      tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";

      columns.forEach(function(cell) {
        // Cell is the property name of every column.
        // row[cell] gives us the value of that cell.
        tableBody = tableBody + "<td>" + row[cell] + "</td>";
      });

      tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>";
    });
  }
}

jQuery("#usersTable").append(tableBody);
```

```html
<table border='1' id="usersTable"></table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y57r4bnk/3/)

[Working version based on feedback](https://jsfiddle.net/y57r4bnk/4/)

Comment: `obj.list(i)` should be `obj.list[i]`. You are calling it as a function now, not accessing a property

Comment: I have updated the question with the corrected syntax.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `obj.list[i].forEach`? `obj.list` is a list of objects, not a list of lists. Just `var row = obj.list[i]`, maybe?

Comment: Originally, `obj.list[i].forEach` would populate each row of the table with all of the objects. Your response is correct. If you can post that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forEach` is an iteration method for arrays, in provided code you're trying to apply this method to object, it's a wrong way. To iterate through object properties you can use `for (var key in object) {"code here"}`. I have corrected your code:

```js
var obj = {
  "list": [{
      "name": "my Name",
      "id": 12,
      "type": "car owner"
    },
    {
      "name": "my Name",
      "id": 13,
      "type": "car owner2"
    },
    {
      "name": "my Name4",
      "id": 14,
      "type": "car owner3"
    },
    {
      "name": "my Name4",
      "id": 15,
      "type": "car owner5"
    }
  ]
};

var tableBody = "";
var columns = [];
var searchField = "name";
var searchVal = "my Name";

tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";
for (var prop in obj.list[0]) {
  if (obj.list[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    tableBody = tableBody + ("<th>" + prop + "</th>");
    columns.push(prop);
  }
}

tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>";

for (var i = 0; i < obj.list.length; i++) {
  if (obj.list[i][searchField] == searchVal) {
    tableBody = tableBody + "<tr>";
    for (var key in obj.list[i]) {
      tableBody = tableBody + "<td>" + obj.list[i][key] + "</td>";
    };
    tableBody = tableBody + "</tr>"; 
  }
}

jQuery("#usersTable").append(tableBody);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' id="usersTable"></table>
```

Comment: Did you test your code? A table is generated but the cells are undefined though I may be missing something.

Comment: @Astron, I'll check it again tomorrow, now i need to sleep ;)